# EXEC_BREAKPOINT swift access data from parse

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to get some data from Parse and I am getting EXEC_BREAKPOINT Error. Info below.

This is my database, to show that column valuesa are correct.
[image]

This is the error during runtime
[image]

This is the point where it breaks
[image]

Here's my code.**If I remove the let statement in code below, issue goes away ... so that's where the error is**
Where's my problem?

```
func getCurrentUserInfo() {
    var query = PFQuery(className: "userstatus")
    query.whereKey("username", equalTo: PFUser.currentUser().username)
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            println("Found something")
            for object in objects {
                println(object.objectId)

                let lastSuccessfulLevel = object["lastSuccessfulLevel"]
                //let score = object["score"]

                println("lastSuccessfulLevel = " + (lastSuccessfulLevel as String))// + ", Score = " + score)
            }
        }
        else {
            println("%@", error)
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: The error says "Swift dynamic cast failed", and I see that `objects` is an array of objects typed AnyObject, maybe casting `score` as an Int would do it? (just a guess looking at your post, I didn't test) `if let score = object["score"] as Int {...}`

Comment: yes that worked. Answer the question and i will mark it as the answer. Noob here so still getting basics right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error says `Swift dynamic cast failed`, and I see that `objects` is an array of objects with type AnyObject, so casting `score` as an Int should do it:

```
if let score = object["score"] as Int {
    println(score)
}
```

And if you're using Swift 1.2:

```
if let score = object["score"] as? Int {
    println(score)
}
```